# Java Runtime exec fails to load the batch file in specific cases

Tags: java, cmd, runtime.exec

This code fails because of having parentheses in the folder name. Java Runtime exec doesn't parse the file location properly. Do you have any suggestions how to fix this?

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class SampObject {

    String command;

    public void launchBatch() {
        String cmdArray[];

        command = "C:\\test(1)folder\\Launch.bat";

        cmdArray = new String[] {
            "cmd",
            "/c",
            "start",
            command
        };

        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdArray);
            System.out.println("Batch file launched");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error launching file: " + e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

public class Sample {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SampObject sampObj = new SampObject();
    sampObj.launchBatch();
}
```

}

Comment: You may want to clarify what "fails" means.

Comment: It doesn't work. The error message I get is 'C:\test' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0):

add quotes to the command:

```
command = "\"C:\\test(1)folder\\Launch.bat\"";
```